# Change stroke color in seleced group

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I try to change stroke color for the group of the path on atrboard. I have document with banch of artboards and icon on each artboards. Each icon contains several groups of the figure. And I have to change that on each artboard. How can I do this with JavaScript in Adobe Illustrator? Thanks.

```
        var doc = app.activeDocument;    
        var strokeColor = {"red":255, "green":0, "blue":0}
        for (i = 0; i < doc.artboards.length; i++) {

        doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(i);
        doc.selectObjectsOnActiveArtboard();

        var selectedObjects = doc.selection;
        var numSelectedObjects = selectedObjects.length; 
        var docSelection = app.activeDocument.selection;

         newRGBColor = new RGBColor ();
         newRGBColor.red=strokeColor.red;
         newRGBColor.green=strokeColor.green;
         newRGBColor.blue=strokeColor.blue;

         docSelection.strokeColor =newRGBColor

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var myStrokeColor = new RGBColor();

myStrokeColor.red = 255;
myStrokeColor.green = 0;
myStrokeColor.blue = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < doc.pathItems.length; i++){
     doc.pathItems[i].strokeColor = myStrokeColor
}
```

You may want to take the time to read [Adobe's documentation on scripting](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/illustrator/scripting.html)

To only change the stroke colour of selected items you can use:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;  
var newRGBColor = new RGBColor();
var mySelection = doc.selection;

newRGBColor.red = 255
newRGBColor.green = 0
newRGBColor.blue = 0


for(var i = 0; i < doc.mySelection; i++){
     mySelection[i].strokeColor = newRGBColor
}
```

Comment: It is a good example but I have a document with many groups on the many artboards and the problem is to change some of them (only selected), not all pathItems.Thanks!